# PostgreSQL: Aliases for "timestamp with time zone" and "at time zone"

Tags: postgresql, time, timezone

I happen to have tables with `timestamp without time zone` column in my database. Now I need to compare them with respect to time zone.

I can do it like:

```
select my_timestamp::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'EST5EDT'
from my_table
where 
    my_timestamp >= '2010-07-01'::timestamp at time zone 'EST5EDT' 
    and my_timestamp < '2010-08-01'::timestamp at time zone 'EST5EDT'
```

This is getting pretty ugly. Is there a shorter way that does not require me to type `timestamp with time zone` as type and `at time zone` as conversion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`timestamptz` is an alias for `timestamp with time zone`, `timestamp` is an alias for `timestamp without time zone`.

I don't think `at time zone` has an alias.